# Venting a 96% furnace

Tags: furnace, venting

I would like to use the existing exhaust ducting from a previous furnace to run the two pvc pipes for 96% furnace up through. I would cut the existing ducting in the attic to run the pvc out the roof. Reason being that it will open up a wall not having the existing ducting boxed around as I am remodeling that bathroom. Just seeking advice, tips or ideas in regards if this is doable and, if so, what it would entail.

Comment: Please reword your post so it has a specific question, as this is a question and answer site.

Comment: The question is if it's doable? As in is there code issues, would 96% furnaces need more access to open air than what would be provided through this access, has anybody done anything like this where you have both pipes exiting the roof in the same larger hole? I didn't realize that this post didn't infer these questions and that reaching out to someone who could enlighten me on what is workable and what isn't wasn't allowed on this site. My apologise. I'll be more specific in asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can vent almost anywhere you like as long as you use the correct size pipe for the length used and it is installed using the furnace MFG recommendations. Usually those type furnaces are vented horizontally through an outside wall using the correct size pipe. You can vent vertically if you follow the correct procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Local codes may apply.  My county for example now require furnace intakes and vents to go thru the roof and not the side of the home.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please take the tour so you know how to participate here. This should be posted in the comment section as it does no answer the question.  ( Granted, there is no specific question.  Still, the answer field is for answers.)  https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour